# In Symfony2 with Doctrine ODM how can I dynamically create fields in a document?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm, odm

I have an Site Record that can contain any number of AdProvider configuration fields with differing information. Unfortunately, the fieldNames (names of the providers) are unique and there will be more coming. I could just hardcode each of them in the Document as hash types, but I would have to update the Document each time a new Provider is added.

I'd like to dynamically modify the Document itself looking at the list of Providers that I can get from another Mongo collection, but I can't figure out how to do this.

My first attempt was to create a listener on the loadClassMetaData event and map the new fields. I'm seeing the field mappings but they aren't reflected in the document. Obviously there aren't any getters and setters for these fields so I tried accessing them with the magic __get and __set methods, but I get errors that they don't exist.

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Example Mongo record:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4ff1d29d99c6667722000000"),
    "_type" : [
        "Models_Site"
    ],
    "enabledAdProviders" : [
        "provider1",
        "provider2",
        "provider3",
        "provider4"
    ],
    "provider1" : {
        "id" : "4028cbff38e2d7c00666fd2fdc770208"
    },
    "provider2" : {
        "placements" : {
            "Top_300x50" : "477",
            "Btm_300x50" : "478",
            "Top_320x50" : "477",
            "Btm_320x50" : "478"
        }
    },
    "provider3" : {
        "id" : "8a809449013331fdcdc6662708532b20"
    },
    "siteId" : "PsTl",
    "siteName" : "Publisher Site",
    "provider4" : {
        "placements" : {
            "Top_300x50" : "430",
            "Btm_300x50" : "430"
        }
    }
}
```

My listener:

```
<?php
namespace BIM\DataBundle\Listener;

use BIM\DataBundle\Document\AdPublisherRecord;
use BIM\DataBundle\Document\AdProviderRecord;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

class AdPublisherSiteSetup
{
private $serviceContainer;

/**
 * This service is called every time Ads doctrine odm loads a document. 
 * We are dynamically creating the ad provider setting nodes on the AdPublisher Record 
 * 
 */
public function __construct($serv){
    $this->serviceContainer = $serv;
}

public function loadClassMetadata(\Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $args)
{
    $metaData = $args->getClassMetadata();
    $document = (string)$metaData->getName();

    if($document == "BIM\DataBundle\Document\AdPublisherRecord"){
        //query for ad providers
        //create as a hash type to store each providers settings.
        $providerList = $this->serviceContainer->get('ads.publisher.factory')->getProviderList();
        foreach ($providerList as $name => $value) {
            $metaData->mapField(array('fieldName' => $name, 'type' => 'hash'));
        }   
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible with doctrine. Doctrine Documents are "static", so the fields you want to load must be present in the document or else will not be loaded. If you could explain a bit more about what you want to achieve I guess there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: I want to be able to have my application work with newly entered Ad Providers (generate the correct form fields needed when creating or editing a Site Record.

Comment: I played around some more and was able to make it work if I modified the classMetadata just before retrieving the records. However, I need to define the property in the Document and use the magic methods, so it seems like there is no advantage to doing this way. I guess I'll just have to add the property, generate getters and setters and redeploy when a new AdProvider is added to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with plain Doctrine-odm, however I've used a simple trick to do almost the same:

---

Since MongodDB Documents can be nested, simply create an `@Hash` property in your doc, that will contains the schema-less properties (think of it as an hash-bag):

```
class Doc {

   /** 
    * Schema-less dynamic properties goes here:
    * @MongoDB\Hash 
    */
   public $extraFields;

   /** @MongoDB\Date */
   public $createdDate;

   //Other static properties...
}
```

The only caveat is that the schema-less properties will go in the `$extraFields` property, and not on the root.

However this is only an aesthetic problem, you can do everything on those fields (indexes, queries, map reduce, ecc)

In this way you can have either statically defined properties (like Id, createdDate, ecc)
and an hash bag of dynamic properties.

If you want to document the existence of some of those dynamic properties (and avoid common typo problems to your colleagues), you can define some access methods in the Doc:

```
class Doc {

    public getExtraName() {
        if(empty($this->extraFields['name'])) return null;
         return $this->extraFields['name'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an extensive EAV system for Symfony2 and Doctrine2-ODM where any document could be turned into a "hybrid" of conventional fields and attributes.  The attributes are all defined in another document with specific types (Address, Phone Number, string, document reference, etc).  I can't share the code because it is company property, but the gist of it is as follows.

- All values of the attributes must be able to be simplified to an array (multi-dimensional is ok also) as these values are stored in a hash field in the document.
- Make an abstract class that you can extend in your document (AbstractAttributeAware) is what I used.  Inside of that class there should be the folowing.

  - **A field called 'updateCount' or something along those lines.  Anytime an attribute is modified, update this update count to force the updating of the document.**
  - A hash field to store the deflated values.
  - A property (not stored in DB) where the objects are stored.
  - "deflate" and "inflate" methods that take the hash values and convert them to objects or take the objects and convert them to the hash.
- Create a listener that listens on persist, update, and load.  These listeners should "inflate" and "deflate" any documents that extend your AbstractAttributeAware class.
- Create a class to be the "AttributeHandler" that deals with the inflation and deflation.  Basically a class to house the inflate and deflate functions.  I suppose you could put them in your listeners instead of you want to.

I'm sorry I couldn't put more down, but I would be glad to help if further clarification is needed.  The key is the updateCount field in bold  (took me forever to get to the bottom of that one).

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of research i came up with the following solution. Hope it may help....
1. Register an event listener in services.yml

services:
  my_doctrine_listener:
        class:   Test\SamplerestBundle\Listener\ModifyColumn
        tags:
            -  { name: doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_listener, event: loadClassMetadata }

2. In  Test\SamplerestBundle\Listener\ModifyColumn add the following method

public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();
        $document = (string)$classMetadata->getName();

```
    if($document == "TestBundle\\Document\\TestDocument"){
        $fieldMapping = array(
            'fieldName' => 'columnTest',
            'type' => 'string'
        );

        /*
        the field is registered as private method
        */
        $classMetadata->reflFields['columnTest'] = new \ReflectionProperty($classMetadata->name,'about');
        $classMetadata->mapField($fieldMapping);
    }

}
```

3. Add magic methods in the Document

   ```
   public function __set($column,$value){
       $this->$column = $value;
   }

   public function __get($column){
       return $this->$column;
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm getting a ReflectionException mentioning that the field does not exist. Because, in the ReflectionProperty constructor, it's checking that the property is available in the class given by the first argument, hence it's throwing an exception.      

And also inside of the mapField method (Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadata), before it add to the reflFields array, it' trying to fetches the new property from the reflection class, so again it's failed there as well.